# Ajax in jQuery - Unintentional loop

Tags: jquery

I don't know why, but when I click in the submit the ajax run repeating for 4x or more times and I just supposed to run once after clicked. I'm a beginner and I've never used JQuery before:

```
    <script type=text/javascript>
    $(document).click(function()
        {
        document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault()
        })

        $("#button").click(function(event)
        {
            let username = document.getElementById("username").value
            $.get("/check?username=" + username, function(data)
            {
                console.log(data)
                if (data)
                {
                    console.log("data == true")
                    alert("Username already in use")
                    return false
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("data == false")
                    document.getElementById("form").submit()
                    return
                }
            }, 'json")
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `$(document).click(function()` ?

Comment: `$(document).click` should be `$(document).ready`

Comment: Don't put click event on $(document) object. This will trigger click event handler everytime there is a click happening inside the whole page. In your case, after listening it will re-register form submission event thus creating multiple submission events,

Answer (score 1):

Try to update `$(document).click(function()` to `$(document).ready(function()`.

```
 $(document).ready(function()
        {
        document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault()
        })

        $("#button").click(function(event)
        {
            let username = document.getElementById("username").value
            $.get("/check?username=" + username, function(data)
            {
                console.log(data)
                if (data)
                {
                    console.log("data == true")
                    alert("Username already in use")
                    return false
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("data == false")
                    document.getElementById("form").submit()
                    return
                }
            }, 'json")
        })
    })
```